# Generating apk and test in android smartphones not work

Tags: android, apk

I created an android application to connect external sql server over WiFi and fetched some data and displayed. I generate its `apk` via `Build>Build apk`. It creates `apk` folder in output folder of `build` which contains `'app.debug.apk'` and `'app.debug.unaligned.apk'`. I installed it in my android smartphone. The app is opened and shows layout. It doesn't shows any error message. But I can't fetch my data from sql server.

I don't know what is the problem with that.
Help me.

Comment: go to Build>Generate Signed Apk... you apk will be having name like **app-realese.apk**. try installing that on device it will work.

Comment: Please add codes so that any one help

Comment: Are you installing the apk in the same device? If yes then try clearing the cash and try again

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow steps for generating **signed APK:**

1. Click on Build > Generate Signed APK in the menu.
2. Click Next to build an APK for the app module.
3. Click on Create New to create a new keystore file.
4. Fill in the fields to create your keystore and key as appropriate.
5. Generate your signed APK.

For pictorial representation and more detailed answer please refer this link : [How to generate signed APK](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/ud853/course_resources/creating-a-signed-apk)