# Android release on play market

Tags: android, android-manifest, release

This is my first time release an app on play market. When i uploaded it for the first time, I got error which says that no device is compatible. Then, I found that I need to add these lines to manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />


<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.StartActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.Activity1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <provider
        android:name=".model.db.Provider"
        android:authorities="com.me.model.db.Provide"
        android:exported="false"
        android:multiprocess="true" />

    <service
        android:name=".model.services.OperationsFinishService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service
        android:name=".model.services.Service"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ui.activities.NoInternetActivity" />
</application>
```

I uploaded it again and I got this same error though. Can anybody show me how to solve this? 
Can it be that I didn't specify what cpu type to support?

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Can these lines make it work?

My gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.me.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 7
    versionName "0.6"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'
        universalApk true
    }
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
compile 'com.github.pro100svitlo:creditCardNfcReader:0.9.1'
compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.0'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but you surely don't need to specify all those compatible screens in your manifest. Perhaps something else in your manifest is causing a problem. Can you post the entire thing?

Comment: @TedHopp, can you have a look again, I uploaded the whole thing

Comment: @RustamIbragimov Can you upload your whole android manifest file?

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: @jankigadhiya, can you have a look again?

Comment: Why you are using splits?? Try removing that part of code..!!

Comment: Have you generated signed Apk if not then take a look at my this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37267325/6127411